# Not able to launch Firefox using maven command

Tags: firefox, maven, selenium, junit4

I am new to maven and selenium.I am using Selenium RC `version:2.16.0`. I am using  maven to generate the html reports. 
Whenever I use the maven commands it is not able to launch a firefox instance. The debug.log is as:

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory - Requested browser string '*chrome' matches *chrome`

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.locators.Firefox2or3Locator - Dicovering Firefox 2...`

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.locators.BrowserLocator - Discovering Firefox 2...`

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.locators.BrowserLocator - Checking whether Firefox 2 launcher at :'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' is valid...`

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.locators.BrowserLocator - Discovered valid Firefox 2 launcher  : 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'`

`DEBUG org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.ResourceExtractor - Extracting /customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME to C:\Users\ADMINI~1.DM2\AppData\Local\Temp\2\customProfileDirb9a7dd64419644668ebc78da85b0c71d`

```
DEBUG org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer - IGNORED 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:450)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.acceptSocket(ThreadedServer.java:432)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer$Acceptor.run(ThreadedServer.java:634)
```

and it keeps on throwing the timeout for indefinite time. Does anyone else has face this issue. My firefox version is `10.1.0`

Comment: i have tried http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/9/27/selenium-and-firefox-3 this tutorial to change the settings to point to latest firefox version. But did not work. Please help..!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue a month ago and solved it by placing the

> firefox.exe

path directory into the environment path variable.